# What is the best way to connect these sentences?

Tags: conjunction, relative-clause, relative-pronoun

> Der Text geht um den fortschritt der privatschulen.

And

> Die Nachfrage nach studienplätzen ist gestiegen.

The relation between the two sentences is a cause-effect where the demand causes the advance.

Comment: _"privatenschulen"_ isn't a commonly used term in german language at all. Could you please give a reference, where you got that from. Also _"Die Nachfrage nach studienplätze ist gestiegen."_ should rather be _"Die Nachfrage nach Studienplätze**n** ist gestiegen."_ Your question is a bit unclear, consider what are your particular concerns please.

Comment: There was just an error where "plätzen" instead of "plätze", but the question is very clear. If you have any reasonable cause you can vote to close the question.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what the relation between the two sentences is?

Comment: @CarstenS It is very clear the relation between these sentences which is cause-effect.

Comment: So the demand caused the text? Or the other way around? Or did the progress cause the demand?

Comment: @CarstenS I have edited the question for more clarification

Comment: @HussienChahin There's nothing really clear (still), as mentioned at least twice! Please try to give more context, and how you're planning to connect those sentences. Otherwise there might be endless variants given as possible answers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have no context,I have two senteces as an answer for a question in my book, and I need to form a coherent answer consisting of these two sentences.

Comment: Take into account that there is absolutely no relationship in the German educational system between "Privatschulen" and "Studienplätzen". This might cause the confusion of many people.

Comment: The above is a comment, not an answer. And comments, are, well, for commenting.

Answer (score 2):

A rather simple way to connect:

> - In dem Text geht es um den Aufschwung der Privatschulen infolge
>   der gestiegenen Nachfrage nach Studienplätzen.
> - In dem Text geht es um die Belebung der Privatschulen infolge
>   der gestiegenen Nachfrage nach Studienplätzen.

Answer (score 0):

> <s>Der Text geht um den fortschritt der privatenschulen.</s>
>
> **In dem** Text geht **es** um **die Ausbreitung** der/von Privatschulen.
>
> Die Nachfrage nach **S**tudienplätze**n** ist gestiegen.

I assume the second sentence is giving the reason for the first.

> In dem Text geht es um die **wegen** der gestiegenen Nachfrage nach Studienplätzen **stattfindenden** Ausbreitung der/von Privatschulen.

*Stattfindenden* is the *Partizip I* of the verb *stattfinden*. This participle is used for inserts that give a simultaneous or concurrent action. In combination with *wegen* it creates a *Klammer* around a reason.

Instead of *stattfinden*, you can also use other verbs, e.g. *geschehen*, *passieren*, even *explodieren*, if you want to say private schools literally **boom**.

---

It's okay, even more natural to use *von+Dativ* instead of *der+Genitiv* in this sentence, as *Privatschulen* is a kind of thing here, not a particular thing.

Comment: Good sentence although a little complex,but not the best